# Stop a reboot that was scheduled by apt unattended-upgrades

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I've already looked at few answers on unattended-upgrades topic but none of them seem to help.

When there is pending reboot and I am logged in to the server I keep getting these notifications to my session:

```
Broadcast message from root@server (Thu 2020-10-15 20:00:00 UTC):
The system is going down for reboot at Fri 2020-10-16 00:00:00 UTC!
```

I know I can disable future runs of apt-upgrade to not reboot by setting
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false"; in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

But I need the cancel the current reboot.
How can I cancel just the above scheduled reboot?

Answer (score 5):

You can cancel a pending [shutdown](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html) using

```
sudo shutdown -c
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this behaviour has been around a long time, and was thankfully kept for systemd. If unattended-upgrades scheduled a reboot, the details will be specified at `/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`. You can verify `shutdown -c` worked by that file no longer being there.